# How do I rollback transactions in multiple classes?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two classes, ServiceA and ServiceB, both which have methods calling the database

in ServiceA i have the following code

```
public void updateData() {
//some database updates
serviceB.addDetails();
//some more database updates
}
```

here is my configuration in applicationContext for both the classes

```
<bean id="serviceATarget" class="com.company.service.ServiceA">
    <property name="serviceB" ref="serviceB" />
    <property name="serviceADAO" ref="serviceADAO" />
</bean>
<bean id="serviceA" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="target" ref="serviceATarget" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
    <props>
        <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="serviceBTarget" class="com.company.service.serviceB">
    <property name="serviceBDAO" ref="serviceBDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="serviceB" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="target" ref="serviceBTarget" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
    <props>
    <prop key="add*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The issue is that in ServiceA, if an exception occurs after the "//some more database updates" section, the updates made in `serviceB.addDetails()` are not being rolled back.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use annotations (it is easier)

"Declarative transaction configuration in versions of Spring 2.0 and above differs considerably from previous versions of Spring. The main difference is that there is no longer any need to configure TransactionProxyFactoryBean beans."

You have like Service A calling Service B and annotate them with @Transactional Propagation.REQUIRED. 
Any exception will rollback your transaction. (if you do not catch and handle it)

Comment: in my application we use xml for configuration so I would prefer sticking to that. And anyways I'm doing the same thing in xml with this line (`<prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception</prop>`) right?

Comment: this didn't work ... i'm doing the same thing in xml anyways.